# Obfuscate string value in configuration file based on build type - Android

Tags: android, security, proguard, android-productflavors, android-build-type

How to obfuscate string values ​​using buildConfigField

Currently we use buildConfigField to declare our variables (keys) by type of build, but when performing the reverse engineering of the APK we can clearly see the values ​​declared with buildConfigField, as shown in the image below.

[BuildConfig file after reverse engineering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4sMi.png)

P.S.: Even using `minifyEnabled` with proguard, we have the problem mentioned

This same discussion is covered in this post -> [Fight against reverse engineering of Android APK](https://medium.com/it-works-locally/fight-against-reverse-engineering-of-android-apk-6fcaee536001), but without a solution

Comment: There is no support for this in the Android SDK. You can look into commercial tools like DexGuard, or find ways to not need these keys (e.g., handle that work on your own server).

Comment: I understand, but in the case of external services, would the suggestion be that the keys escape the API? The API key would still be visible when performing reverse engineering, right?

Comment: I do not know what "keys escape the API" means, sorry. "The API key would still be visible when performing reverse engineering, right?" -- yes. The API would still be visible even with DexGuard, though in that case they would need to use a debugger. By definition, for the API key to be usable, it has to exist in a form that could be found by an attacker. What DexGuard or similar tools do is increase the difficulty, not block it entirely.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help. Too bad the SDK has no way of obfuscating variables in reverse engineering, especially build type variables

Comment: That's not possible from a computing standpoint, other than obfuscating to the DexGuard level. In the end, you need the key in an un-obfuscated form to use the API. That means *something* has to decrypt the value, and that something has to be in the app. This means that the decrypted value can be seen at runtime via a debugger, and in principle somebody could figure out the decryption key and decyrypt it statically. DexGuard-level obfuscation means somebody has to go through that work, but it doesn't prevent finding the un-obfuscated API key.

Comment: In terms of why the Android SDK doesn't do it... this is not really an Android problem. Any client-side code (Android, iOS, desktop, JavaScript in a Web browser) has the same issue. If the API key is on the client, somebody determined enough can get to it. All we can do is put up barriers to slow them down, in hopes that most people will not bother trying.